# Problemas consulta con joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Hola estoy tratando de hacer count de una determinada columna para una consulta a traves de graphql y rails. la consulta es la siguiente:

```
    feedback_types_text = Feedback
               .joins('INNER JOIN feedback_texts ON feedbacks.id = feedback_texts.id')
               .joins('INNER JOIN feedback_audios ON feedbacks.id = feedback_audios.id')
               .where('feedbacks.finished = true')
               .select("COUNT(feedback_texts.id, feedback_audios.id) as total")
    feedback_types_text
```

todo resulta bien si en el count solo coloco feedback_texts.id, pero si agrego otra columna dentro en consola me salta un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontrada la solución, debia hacer un count para cada columna por separado dejando un alias "as total(ejemplo)" ademas de utilizar distinct para especificar que sea esa columna y para finalizar se debio aplicar LEFT join en vez de INNER, ya que quiero que me retornen todas las rows de la tabla izquierda aun asi no hayan matches con la derecha. cuando utilizaba inner join solo traia rows que hacian match entre las tablas.

```
 feedback_types_text = Feedback.select("COUNT(distinct feedback_texts.id) as total, COUNT(distinct feedback_audios.id) as total_audios")
           .joins('LEFT JOIN feedback_texts ON feedbacks.id = feedback_texts.id')
           .joins('LEFT JOIN feedback_audios ON feedbacks.id = feedback_audios.id')
           .where('feedbacks.finished = true')

feedback_types_text
```